# Randomly drop % of rows by condition in polars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, python-polars

Imagine we have the following polars dataframe:

| Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Labels |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 25 | 1 |
| 150 | 18 | 0 |
| 200 | 15 | 0 |
| 230 | 28 | 0 |
| 120 | 12 | 1 |
| 130 | 34 | 1 |
| 150 | 23 | 1 |
| 180 | 25 | 0 |

Now using polars we want to drop every row with `Labels == 0` with 50% probability. An example output would be the following:

| Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Labels |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 25 | 1 |
| 200 | 15 | 0 |
| 230 | 28 | 0 |
| 120 | 12 | 1 |
| 130 | 34 | 1 |
| 150 | 23 | 1 |

I think [filter](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html) and [sample](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.sample.html) might be handy... I have something but it is not working:

```
df = df.drop(df.filter(pl.col("Labels") == 0).sample(frac=0.5))
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: For you working well `df.filter(pl.col("Labels") == 0).sample(frac=0.5)` ? Then use `df = df.drop(df.filter(pl.col("Labels") == 0).sample(frac=0.5).index)`

Comment: @jezrael I tried the pandas way, but I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: OK, can you try `df.filter(pl.col("Labels") == 0).sample(frac=0.5).vstack(df.filter(pl.col("Labels") != 0))`

Comment: `df.drop(df[df['Labels']==0].sample(frac=0.5).index)`

Comment: @jezrael thank you! That approach does work, however I would like the data to still be shuffled. Is there any way to avoid segregating `Labels==0` from `Labels!=0`?

Comment: Okay I found shuffle from polars, nice! :)

Comment: @Janikas - Can you test edited answer? I add row count column and then sorting after `vstack`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`polars.DataFrame.vstack`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.vstack.html):

```
df = (df.filter(pl.col("Labels") == 0).sample(frac=0.5)
        .vstack(df.filter(pl.col("Labels") != 0))
        .sample(frac=1, shuffle=True))
```

Comment: Is the `sort` used for shuffle?

Comment: @Janikas - no, need `sample`, answer was edited.

Comment: That's exactly how I shuffled it! Thank you my friend! :)